# Codeigniter 4 Handle Request URI Segment If the URL is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, codeigniter-4

I am using Codeigniter 4 framework and I have a function for getting the URI segment like

```
    $bahasa = $request->uri->getSegment(1);
    $url = $request->uri->getSegment(2);
    $content = $request->uri->getSegment(3);
```

the code is working if the URL most like:
`http://localhost:8080/segment1/segment2/segment3`
but if I put the URL like `http://localhost:8080/segment1/` the code is an error, the error is
`CodeIgniter\HTTP\Exceptions\HTTPException Request URI segment is out of range: 2`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to check availability of your segement request

```
if($request->uri->getSegment(2) || $request->uri->getSegment(3)){
//response if the request is available
}else{
//response if the request is not available
}
```

if you still confuse you can read this documentation :
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#creating-uri-instances

Answer (score 1):

##### Solution

[Disable Throwing Exceptions](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#disable-throwing-exceptions)

> By default, some methods of this class may throw an exception. If you
> want to disable it, you can set a special flag that will prevent
> throwing exceptions.
>
> ```php
> <?php
>
> // Disable throwing exceptions
> $uri->setSilent();
>
> // Enable throwing exceptions (default)
> $uri->setSilent(false);
> ```

Hence if your sample URI is `http://localhost:8080/segment1/`:

```php
// $bahasa will be set to 'segment1'.
$bahasa = $request->uri->setSilent()->getSegment(1);
// $url will be set to '' (empty string).
$url = $request->setSilent()->uri->getSegment(2);
// $content will be set to '' (empty string).
$content = $request->setSilent()->uri->getSegment(3);
```

##### Extra tip:

> You can also set a different default value for a particular segment by
> using the second parameter of the `getSegment()` method. The default
> is empty string. - [URI Segments](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#uri-segments)

Answer (score 0):

Just use ***isset*** function to check either the segment is exists or not. Like bellow:

```
$url = isset( $request->uri->getSegment(2) ) ? $request->uri->getSegment(2) : '';
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

best way to handle local and server segment issue need to change getSegment function

getSegment function you can find system/http/URI.php

getSegment function will look like this by default

```
public function getSegment(int $number, string $default = ''): string
    {
        // The segment should treat the array as 1-based for the user
        // but we still have to deal with a zero-based array.
        $number--;

        if ($number > count($this->segments) && ! $this->silent) {
            throw HTTPException::forURISegmentOutOfRange($number);
        }

        return $this->segments[$number] ?? $default;
    }
```

need to change segment number like

```
 public function getSegment(int $number, string $default = ''): string
    {
        // The segment should treat the array as 1-based for the user
        // but we still have to deal with a zero-based array.
         $hostname= getenv('HTTP_HOST'); 
          if($hostname=='localhost'){
            $number--;
          }else{ 
//live server 
            $number=$number-2;
          }
        if ($number > count($this->segments) && ! $this->silent) {
            throw HTTPException::forURISegmentOutOfRange($number);
        }
    
        return $this->segments[$number] ?? $default;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a native way to do this. The first one I tested. The second should work according to the docs I was using.

```
$uri = current_url(true);
if($uri->getTotalSegments() > 0) {
   $bahasa = $uri->getSegment(1);
}
if$uri->getTotalSegments() > 1) {
    $url = $uri->getSegment(2);
}
if($uri->getTotalSegments() > 2) {
    $content = $uri->getSegment(3);
}

OR

if($request->getUri()->getTotalSegments() > 0) {
   $bahasa = $request->getUri()->getSegment(1);
}
if$request->getUri()->getTotalSegments() > 1) {
    $url = $request->getUri()->getSegment(2);
}
if($request->getUri()->getTotalSegments() > 2) {
    $content = $request->getUri()->getSegment(3);
}
```